# Change pointer for checkbox html

Tags: html, css, checkbox, mouse-cursor

I am new to html and css. Currently I have a checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
```

When I hover over the checkbox, I need a hand icon.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you mean when hovering the input you want to have a custom image cursor?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use the `pointer` CSS style to change the default cursor to a *pointer hand*.

First, add an ID or class to your checkbox.

```
<input id="chkBike" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
```

And in your CSS, use the following style.

```
#chkBike{
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: there is no need to have separate styles..  the default cursor will never be seen here.   only needed:  `#chkBike { cursor: pointer; }`

Answer (score 15):

Using `cursor:pointer` you can achieve this

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br>
```

Answer (score 7):

Anyone use `<label>` markup. Don't know why, but without it the `cursor:pointer;` is only for the check square, and if you click on the text the checkbox doesn't change state.(and I think this is very annoying)
My advice is to use label

```css
input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="checkbox"]+label{
  cursor:pointer;
  }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" id="vehicleId">
<label for="vehicleId">I have a bike</label>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do that using style attribute

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" style="cursor:pointer"/>I have a bike<br>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
input[type="checkbox"] {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```css
input
{
  cursor:pointer
  }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike">I have a bike<br
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want like this:-

```
label, input[type="checkbox"] {
    cursor: pointer;
}
<label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> I have a bike</label>
```

Comment: And you may want to have the cursor change over submit and buttons: `label, input[type="checkbox"], input[type=submit], input[type=button]`

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS cursor property, see [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp) the reference:

```
 input { cursor: pointer }
```

Answer (score 1):

Set an id to corresponding input

```
<input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike" id="vehicleId">I have a bike<br>
```

and apply style css `cursor: pointer` when it hover's
like below shown

```
#vehicleId:hover{cursor:pointer};
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using the custom boostrap checkbox, you can use:

```
.checkbox-pointer .custom-control-label::before, 
.checkbox-pointer .custom-control-label::after {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```